# Can not Generate SSPI context in SQL Server, Windows 10

Tags: c#, sql-server, remote-access, sspi

I'm creating a C# application which accesses a SQL Server database on another PC in the local network. I have Windows 7 running on my PC and have SQL Server installed, and Windows 10 running on the remote PC from where I am accessing the database.

I am getting an error

> Cannot generate SSPI context

when I try to connect to the SQL Server remotely from SSMS on client PC.

1. I have installed the same SQL Server version on the client PC
2. I checked to allow remote connections for the SQL Server
3. I allow connection in firewall

I have connection string below that I am using to access the database from remote pc

```
<add name="FazalConstructions.Properties.Settings.ConnString"
     connectionString="Data Source=192.168.10.2;Initial Catalog=FCProject;persist security info=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What else do I have to do?

Comment: Check this question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812541/cannot-create-sspi-context) it might help.

Comment: i have checked this and i have also tested it with Microsoft Keberos Configuration tool, it says that i have permission issues, how i can fix this issue?

Comment: did you try to connect to the server using SSMS?

Comment: i tried, same error there

Comment: Are the PCs actually joined together on a domain?  It sounds like they're not, and if that's the case they can't really authenticate with each other, whcih would mean you'd have to use SQL Server logins.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no magical answer here, the issue can be any one of the mirriad causes of this problem. Read and follow the troubleshooting steps from these links to find what causes *your* issue:

- [Common ‘SSPI handshake failed’ errors and troubleshooting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2016/02/11/common-sspi-handshake-failed-errors-and-troubleshooting/)
- [“Cannot Generate SSPI Context” error message, more comments for SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2005/10/14/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message-more-comments-for-sql-server/)
- [Using Kerberos with SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2005/10/11/using-kerberos-with-sql-server/)